# not splitting div's properly

Tags: css, html

This has probably been posted before, but I couldn't find a solution from searching. I'm new to HTML and CSS just started ~1 week ago, so if there is a solution an explanation would go a long way rather than modified code/solution.

So I am attempting to split a div into essentially two columns one of 25% width and the other 75% width. I haven't started doing the CSS yet hence why the styling is inline at the moment. The general div of 100% width displays fine now when I try to split this into two inner div's it seems to work the list i am trying to create displays correctly however the next column of 75% appears below the div. Why is this and is there anyway to fix it.

```
<div style="width:100%;background:orange">
    <div style = "text-align:center;width:25%;background-color:red;">
       A List
      <ul>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="width:75%;background:purple;">
        dsfsdf
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that all of your code? Did you set `margin` to zero somewhere?

Comment: This isn't all of the code in my .html file. I'm creating a header a line below this header. Under this there is a general horizontal navigation bar ie - the typical home about etc. In thi css I have a margin set to 0. Then this code is directly after setting the navigation bar, but nothing is setting the margin for this to zero or maybe I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make `<div>`s align next to each other they need to `float`.

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: orange;
    width:100%;
}
.leftColumn {
    float:left;
    background-color: red;
    width:25%;
    margin:0;
}
.rightColumn {
    float:right;
    background-color: purple;
    width:75%;
    margin:0;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftColumn">
       A List
      <ul>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rightColumn">
        dsfsdf
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>Next content</div>
```

To continue with your code below you need an element that `clears` the floating.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7pd2fLf/2/

Answer (score 0):

add style `float:left` to both the div with width 25% and 75% and run your code
add `<div style="clear:both"></div>`

Comment: I know that would work, but doesn't this essentially make the general div I created to contain these have a height of 0? And if I wanted to structure div's under these they wouldn't appear under this div now?

Comment: @Skeletor: you'd need to add a div which "clears" the floating: `clear:both`, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7pd2fLf/

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, now I understand thank you for the answers and the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Create like this your html and css:

```css
.orange-div{
  width:100%;
  background:orange;
  float: left;
  
}
.red-div{
 text-align:center;
  width:25%;
  background-color:red;
  float: left;
}
.purple-div{
  width:75%;
  background:purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="orange-div">
    <div class="red-div">
       A List
      <ul>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
         <li> something</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="purple-div">
        dsfsdf
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do these things with Flexbox. If you're new, don't learn to use float for layout. Flexbox is made for this.

And use classes:

```
.container {
    display: flex; /* makes container a flex parent and all its children flex children */
}
.left,
.right {
    flex: 1; /* give 1 'part' of total width */
}
.right {
    flex: 3; /* give 3 'parts' of total width */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/tuojmn3g/

The `flex` property is very cool. If you give both children `flex: 1`, all children will be equal size: 50% (because `1 : 1`). If you then give 1 of the children `flex: 3`, it will be 3x as big as the other (because `1 : 3`). This gives you immense flexibility.

Flexbox is complicated but it's very well worth it to learn.

And a Flexbox bonus: equal height columns for free!